# Ubuntu: Error installing php5-xsl package

Tags: xslt, ubuntu-8.10

I am trying to install php5-xsl (XSLT) package in my Ubuntu 8.10 but I am getting an error message. I think I need to update the repository of the apt-get? Thanks in advance :) - Mark

My syntax:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

Error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xsl_5.2.6-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
  404 Not Found
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted at SuperUser?

Comment: thanks for listing the name! :D

Answer (score 7):

My bad. I forgot to update my repository. It works now using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```